# React function not activating

Tags: reactjs

In React i have window.onscroll function that when scrolled down should activate 
change function that sets setState classAnimation to 'testing2'.

For some reason change function does not activate. it gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'change' of undefined.

My end goal is to add class called testing2 to state property and change the
onscreen text to red when user scrolls down more then 50px.

Help would be nice.

**APP.JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Animations from './components/animations';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

this.state = {
  classAnimation: '' 
};

this.change = this.change.bind(this);

}


change = () => {
    this.setState({
      classAnimation: 'testing2'
    });
}



  componentDidMount() {
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    function myFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop 
> 50) {
      this.change();
  } else {

      }
    }
   }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Animations testing={this.state.classAnimation}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**ANIMATION.JS**

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = (props) => {

    return(
        <div>
                <div className={props.testing}>very good test it is</div>
        </div>
        );
    };

export default Home;
```

**APP.CSS**

```
    body{
  height:1500px;
}

#myP{
  position:fixed;
}


.testing2{
  position:fixed;
  color:red;
}
```

**THIS IS WHAT I GET:**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'change' of undefined

**THIS IS WHAT I WANT:**

Changing text called Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
to red when user has scrolled down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main problems here.

***Setting the `scroll` events should go like this:***

```
myFunction = () => {
    //your logic
}

componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.myFunction)
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.myFunction)
}
```

***You are binding an arrow function(lexical this). Either use class method notation or arrow functions without `bind`:***

```
change = () =>{/* Don't bind this */}

change(){/* Should be binded in `constructor` */}
```

Comment: This is it. I was creating a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/soanswer57254583-ccum7) before posting an answer and this answer should work and even better as it removes the even listener.

Answer (score 0):

You have lost context of the `this` object . Within

```
function myFunction() {}
```

you have new scope, and hence `this` loses its context. You'll need to place myFunction as a method and bind it to the scope in your constructor.

Your solution as it stands has `myFunction()` calling `this.change` which means that the compiler is looking for `change` within `myFunction()` which is obviously not how your code is structured.

Something like this would serve you:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
     classAnimation: '' 
  };

this.change = this.change.bind(this);
this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
}


change() {
    this.setState({
    classAnimation: 'testing2'
   });
}

myFunction() {
   // Code for myFunction that calls this.change
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.myFunction);
}
```